# How to add options to ntpd

Tags: c, autoconf, ntp, ntpd, autogen

I'd like to add a new option to ntpd however I couldn't find how to generate `ntpd/ntpd-opts{.c, .h}` after adding some lines to `ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def` e.g.,

```
$ git diff ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
diff --git a/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def b/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
index 66b953528..a790cbd51 100644
--- a/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
+++ b/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
@@ -479,3 +479,13 @@ flag = {
        the server to be discovered via mDNS client lookup.
        _EndOfDoc_;
 };
+
+flag = {
+    name      = foo;
+    value     = F;
+    arg-type  = number;
+    descrip   = "Some new option";
+    doc = <<-  _EndOfDoc_
+       For testing purpose only.
+       _EndOfDoc_;
+};
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You're asking in the wrong place. Ask the authors about that. Read the docs. Read build files. Maybe read the changes from previous commits. For a question here, you'd have to extract a [mcve] first, by which time you'd know what to do probably.

Comment: I am asking here because it seems that the NTP community is almost inactive (e.g., their mailing list is not working and GitHub repo is not maintained). I have asked same things at Google Group but no responses.

Answer (score 1):

> how to generate ntpd/ntpd-opts{.c, .h} after adding some lines to ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def

It is just in build scripts. Just compile https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/master-no-authorname/INSTALL#L30 it normally and make will pick it up.

https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/master-no-authorname/ntpd/Makefile.am#L304

https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/master-no-authorname/ntpd/Makefile.am#L183

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @KamilCuk's answer, we need to do the following to add custom options:

1. Edit `*.def` file
2. Run `bootstrap` script
3. Run `configure` script with `--disable-local-libopts` option
4. Run make

For example,

```
$ git diff ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
diff --git a/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def b/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
index 66b953528..a790cbd51 100644
--- a/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
+++ b/ntpd/ntpdbase-opts.def
@@ -479,3 +479,13 @@ flag = {
        the server to be discovered via mDNS client lookup.
        _EndOfDoc_;
 };
+
+flag = {
+    name      = foo;
+    value     = F;
+    arg-type  = number;
+    descrip   = "Some new option";
+    doc = <<-  _EndOfDoc_
+       For testing purpose only.
+       _EndOfDoc_;
+};
```

This change yields:

```
$ ./ntpd --help
ntpd - NTP daemon program - Ver. 4.2.8p15
Usage:  ntpd [ -<flag> [<val>] | --<name>[{=| }<val>] ]... \
                [ <server1> ... <serverN> ]
  Flg Arg Option-Name    Description
   -4 no  ipv4           Force IPv4 DNS name resolution
                                - prohibits the option 'ipv6'
   ...
   -F Num foo            Some new option
      opt version        output version information and exit
   -? no  help           display extended usage information and exit
   -! no  more-help      extended usage information passed thru pager

Options are specified by doubled hyphens and their name or by a single
hyphen and the flag character.
...
```